# Extending SafeHandle to automatically invoke a function when handle is set

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, reference-counting

Is there a way to implement a SafeHandle class that can be made to automatically call a function when its handle field is set to a valid value? (much in the same way that Release abstract function is called when the SafeHandle is destroyed)

I need to manually call a native dll function to increase the reference count of a handle whenever I take a reference to one from the native dll.

Comment: This won't work; SafeHandle is a 'magic' class and gets special treatment from the P/Invoke marshalling system. The handle field gets set automatically by the framework.

Comment: My own class won't get the special treatment from the CLR that SafeHandle does

Comment: The CLR gives special treatment to the SafeHandle class. It's not possible to get that treatment without using SafeHandle.

Comment: I think you already know the answer to that. Anyway, I've made a mess of your question. I'll delete my comments to remedy that. Sorry.

Comment: It seems like you will have to wrap the first native P/Invoke function with a C# function which will call the second native increment function?